# Setup drawn rectangle collsion in canvas element that follows mouse

Tags: javascript, canvas, mouse

I'm working on a camera software, almost everything in it works, but when the mouse goes off screen it also captures pictures outside the void. I need a way to make the capture box stop at the borders of the canvas.

I've heard of using math.min/max to do boundaries but I can't make heads or tails out of how that would actually work.

```
obligatory code tag because no one-part of my code would make any sense to refrence here.
Math.max([value1[, value2[, ...]]])
Math.min([value1[, value2[, ...]]])
```

https://jsfiddle.net/fzv80a5e/

Comment: And what would that code snippet be exactly? I don't know what code I need, I don't know what terms would get me that answer, I have no idea where to start. I can explain my situation in English, but have no idea where to start with the javascript of it.

Comment: did you read my comment or original post? there is no existing code in my code that refers to the problem because I have no idea where to start with it. It's cool I'll go to another website for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is a simple check for where the current position (X/Y) is on the box and what the min/max dimensions of the canvas is and then just force the box's position to the min or max if it is about to exceed either.
https://jsfiddle.net/0dfs9ynk/

```
function update() {
  context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height); //clear previously drawn rectangles
  context.strokeStyle = '#f00'; //set stroke color
  context.lineWidth = 2;
  if(mouseX <= 0){
    mouseX = 0;
  }
  if(mouseY <= 0){
    mouseY = 0;
  }
  if(mouseX + selectionX >= canvas.width){
    mouseX = canvas.width - selectionX;
  }
  if(mouseY + selectionY >= canvas.height){
    mouseY = canvas.width - selectionY;
  }
  context.strokeRect(mouseX, mouseY, selectionX, selectionY); //set selection size

  requestAnimationFrame(update);
}
```